# Uniformly random number on $[0,1]$ has zero entropy?

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I am computing then entropy of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$:

$$ H(X) = \frac{1}{1-0} \int_0^1 (1 - 0) \log 1 \, dx = 0 $$

Does that mean at $X$ has zero entropy?

Comment: @ElchananSolomon what am I missing?  $\log 1 = 0$

Comment: Sorry, I misread! What you wrote is correct.

Comment: Which definition of entropy are you using? ["The Shannon entropy is restricted to random variables taking discrete values."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))

Comment: There is [differential entropy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy). Wikipedia says it can be zero or even negative.

Answer (score 10):

A random number uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ (actually, in any interval of positive measure) has infinite entropy - if we are speaking of the Shannon entropy $H(X)$, which corresponds to the average information content of each ocurrence of the variable. Indeed, in a real number on the interval $[0,1]$ I can code all the information of the wikipedia, math.stackexchange.com and more.

The *[differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Differential_entropy)* $h(X)$ is another thing. It's not a true entropy (it can be zero or negative), and among other things it depends on the scale (so, say, the -differential- entropy of the height of the humans gives different values if I measure them in centimeters or in inches - which is rather  ridiculous).

So, yes, the differential entropy of your variable is zero. But (because the differential entropy is not the Shannon entropy) that means nothing special - in particular, it does not mean that the variable has no uncertainty -like a constant. Actually, the differential entropy of a constant variable (which would correspond to a Dirac delta density) is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right.

Shannon's definition of the entropy of a continuous random variable $X$ is
$$
H(X)=-E[ln(f(x))]
$$
where $f(x$) is its probability density function. The probability density function for a uniform distribution is $f(x)=1$ if $x \in [0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise. Of course
$$
H(X) = -\int_0^1 ln(1) f(x) dx = 0
$$
in this case.  It even makes sense in a physical system.  If the temperature of a metal bar is equal everywhere, then there's no heating or cooling anywhere in that system.

Comment: But Shannon's entropy is **only** defined for *discrete* r.v's. The above is a (not-always meaningful) continuous analogue, differential entropy, which loses many nice properties of Shannon entropy -- it can be negative, it depends on the scaling, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what my comment says.

Comment: Yes, thank you. You're comment is correct.  Sorry for my temporary inattention.

Answer (score -1):

Using the comment of Clement C, divide the interval into n subintrvals.  Then $H_n(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{-log_2(\frac{1}{n})}{n}=log_2(n)$ so that $H(X)=\infty$