# Can entropy be negative?

Tags: variance, information-theory, entropy

I've been asked the following question, and I can't solve it definitively. I've solved the first part, but I'm not sure about whether entropy can be negative or not. It wouldn't make much sense for it to be, but just by using inequalities and basic maths, I get the following inequality: $$\sigma^2 < \frac{1}{2e^{}\pi}$$ If that is satisfied, then the entropy is negative, and it certainly makes sense for the variance to be able to take that value. So am I going wrong somewhere, or can the entropy be negative? [image: Question regarding entropy]

Comment: Is $p(x)$ the density?  If so, then $0 \leq p(x) \leq 1$, so $\log(p(x))$ is always negative, giving $-\log(p(x))$ always positive.  And the expectation of a positive quantity is....

Comment: Also, it would be most helpful if you showed **how** you were deducing $\sigma^2 < \frac{1}{2e\pi}$ since your entire question hinges on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniformly random number on $[0,1]$ has zero entropy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552895/uniformly-random-number-on-0-1-has-zero-entropy)

Comment: The differential entropy is not the Shannon entropy, it can be negative or zero.

Comment: I am deducing that $$\sigma^2 < \frac{1}{2e^{}\pi}$$ by writing the following and working from there: $$\frac{\ln(2\pi\sigma^2)}{2} + \frac{1}{2} < 0$$

Comment: I am pretty sure I am being asked for the Shannon entropy, given the formula supplied. Also, I 100% get that if $$p(x)$$ is the probability density then it's done (and I'm pretty sure that this is the case), but I'm being asked to use the right hand side of the equation to prove it, and the right hand side of the equation seems like it could be negative.

Comment: Asked tons of times (one of them, two hours ago)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565670/how-can-differential-entropy-be-negative

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can differential entropy be negative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565670/how-can-differential-entropy-be-negative)

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! Apologies for taking up your time.